# Pass struct interface to sqlite exec

Tags: sqlite, go, struct, go-sqlite3

In Go, I'm trying to pass an `interface{}` to the `statement.Exec()` function from `go-sqlite3`. I'm sure this is a solved problem, but I cannot figure it out.

Basically I have a `struct` with the row data which I want to pass to a function that will insert it to a sqlite db. The thing is I want to be able to programmatically control what goes into the  `statement.Exec()` function

Here is an excerpt:

```golang
type hostRows struct {
    domain   string
}

type clientRows struct {
    name   string
}

func main() {

    ...

    data := hostRows{domain: "dom.com"}
    insertRow(sqliteDatabase, data)

    data2 := clientRows{name: "bob"}
    insertRow(sqliteDatabase, data2)

    ...

}

func insertRow(db *sql.DB, row interface{}) {

    insertSQL := "INSERT INTO table(col) VALUES (?)"
    statement, _ := db.Prepare(insertSQL)
    
    statement.Exec(row) // here's the issue, how can I extract the element in the interface to pass it to the function for Exec to understand
    
}
```

I know that in this example, I could hard code the row type to the struct and type `statement.Exec(row.(hostRows).domain)`, but now the code will break to when the client struct is passed.

here is the deceleration for the `Exec` function

```golang
func (s *Stmt) Exec(args ...interface{}) (Result, error)
```

I've tried playing with `reflect` but it hasn't worked for me so far.
My only solution for the moment is using a `switch` condition that could check and prepare the right command for `Exec`, but this is less than dodgy.

```golang
type hostRows struct {
    domain   string
}

type clientRows struct {
    name   string
}

func main() {

    ...

    data := hostRows{domain: "dom.com"}
    insertRow(sqliteDatabase, 1, data)

    data2 := clientRows{name: "bob"}
    insertRow(sqliteDatabase, 2, data2)

    ...

}

func insertRow(db *sql.DB, i int, row interface{}) {

    insertSQL := "INSERT INTO table(col) VALUES (?)"
    statement, _ := db.Prepare(insertSQL)
    
    // This basically could be a working solution, but I'm sure there is a better one
    switch i {
        case 1:
            data := row.(hostRows)
            statement.Exec(data.domain)
        case 2:
            data := row.(clientRows)
            statement.Exec(data.name)
    }
    
}
```

edit: corrected the INSERT statement ; forget the columns. corrected `statement.Exec(row.domain)` to `statement.Exec(row.(hostRows).domain)`
edit2: added second example

Comment: What SQL statement exactly should be generated for insertRow with a hostRows? What with clientRow? Please give an example as struct cannot be used as arguments to Exec.

Comment: That's basically my question. How can I pass the elements of a struct when the name of the variables in the struct can change depending on which one I send to `insertRow`?

Comment: @Volker I added a second example of the type of behaviour I'm looking for though the solution is boilerplate bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in order for `reflect.Interface()` to work, you **must** export the fields. To achieve what you want using reflection, you could try something like this:

```
type hostRows struct {
    //Should export field to read it using reflect.Value.Interface()
    Domain string
}

type clientRows struct {
    //Should export field to read it using reflect.Value.Interface()
    Name string
}

func insertRow(db *sql.DB, i int, row interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(row)
    var args []interface{}
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        args = append(args, rv.Field(i).Interface())
    }
    db.Exec("Insert Satement...", args...)
}
```

Comment: Genius, thanks, I guess I was on the right track but I had forgotten about exporting the fields from the struct. This is still a concept I struggle to work with. Thanks @Pablo